# Passing string array to dxl script in batch mode [doors 9.6]

Tags: python, arrays, list, ibm-doors

The goal:

- I need to pass an **array** of strings (or object identifiers, or integers..) to a dxl script in batch mode.

The issue:

- When passing the array parameter, the cmd prompt pops up, meaning that an error happened (no stderr redirect for the moment)

How am I doing:

- the full command when using an int array is the following:

  `r'"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors" -d 36677@server.com -u user -P passw -p PRJ -dxl "int reqName[]={{1,2,3,4}}; string planned=\"TestPlanned {}\"; string result=\"TestResult {}\" " -batch "script.dxl" > D:\output.txt'`
- the script is populated in python using  .format{} and then launched using subprocess.check_output. In order to test it, it's sufficient to launch the command fromcommand line placing like this:

  `r'"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors" -d 36677@server.com -u user -P passw -p PRJ -dxl "int reqName[]={{1,2,3,4}}; string planned=\"TestPlanned 1\"; string result=\"TestResult 1\" " -batch "script.dxl" > D:\output.txt'`

as a side note, the `D:\output.txt is` never created or populated, so maybe I am missing something also here.

The script actually just prints (couts) the value or the size of the params received:

```
cout<< planned "\r\n"
cout<< result "\r\n"
print sizeof(reqName)""
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work as written- the 'script.dxl' is being evaluated in a separate context from the -dxl that you're asking the item to run on the command line.

Also, dxl doesn't use ; as end lines, so you might want to review your syntax generally.

Options:

1. You could use evalTop_ in the -dxl, something like -dxl "evalTop_(\"int reqName[]={1,2,3,4}\"" which will shove a variable reqName into the global context of DOORS. Just be super careful with these, as any other script calling reqName will get this variable and type, so you should make the name significantly more specific.
2. Skip the -dxl and have your python re-write some part of script.dxl - you should be able to treat .dxl files like .txt files generally, but if needed I guess your python script could just write to txt and then copy over onto a dxl.

Let me know if I've misunderstood something!

Note- edited to escape backslashes in option 1